# Unable to create admin user in CouchDB

Tags: curl, couchdb

I've installed CouchDB, but I am not able to create a user account with admin rights.

```
curl -s -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/admins/xyz -d '"qwerty"'

{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
```

If I am giving the **curl localhost:5984**, then I'm not getting the uuid.

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.1.1","features":["scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to modify configuration with `curl`, you have to include the CouchDB `_node` with which you are concerned. The node info is disclosed by: `... /_node/couchdb@127.0.0.1/ ...`

Secondly, your curl command should contain authorization with an existing admin username/password to be able to modify the CouchDB node configuration. An existing admin is authorized by: `... admin:****@192.168.1.100 ...`

Therefore, this command works for me:

```
$ curl -k -X PUT https://admin:****@192.168.1.100:6984/_node/couchdb@127.0.0.1/_config/admins/xyz -d '"qwerty"'
```

It creates the `xyz` admin for me without any problem:

[image: New "xyz" admin is created]

---

Notice that I'm using port `6984` since I have enabled the `HTTPS` for my CouchDB.